# How to pass command line arguments to a task?

Tags: command-line-arguments, nim-lang, nimble-nim

How do I pass command line arguments to a nimble task? For example, say I have the task

```
task mytask, "my task":
    echo &"my task {args}"
```

When I run

```
nimble mytask --foo --bar
```

I would like nimble to output

```
mytask --foo --bar
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

from nimble [documentation](https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble) (i.e. github's README.md):

> Tasks support two kinds of flags: `nimble <compflags> task <runflags>`. Compile flags are those specified before the task name and are forwarded to the Nim compiler that runs the .nimble task. This enables setting `--define:xxx` values that can be checked with when `defined(xxx)` in the task, and other compiler flags that are applicable in Nimscript mode. Run flags are those after the task name and are available as command-line arguments to the task. They can be accessed per usual from `commandLineParams: seq[string]`.

[commandLineParams](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#commandLineParams) is available in `std/os`. For your example:

```
import std / [os, strformat]

task mytask, "my task":
    echo &"my task {commandLineParams()}"
```

**Update:**

Setting up a new nimble project with the above code added and running:

```
nimble mytask --foo --bar
```

you will actually find that it prints a nim sequence with ALL arguments and not only the runtime flags. For example on Windows and anonymizing specific folder names:

```
my task @["e", "--hints:off", "--verbosity:0", "--colors:on", "XXX\\nimblecache-0\\test_nimble_2483249703\\test_nimble.nims", "XXY\\test_nimble\\test_nimble.nimble", "XXZ\\nimble_23136.out", "mytask", "--foo", "--bar"]
```

So in order to get only `--foo` and `--bar` you need to select arguments after `mytask`

**Note**: we probably should fix nimble docs about that.

Answer (score 1):

Passing just the right arguments:

```py
proc forward_args(task_name: string): seq[string] =
  let args = command_line_params()
  let arg_start = args.find(task_name) + 1
  return args[arg_start..^1]

task dev, "Start the project in dev mode":
  const params = forward_args("dev").join(" ")
  exec &"nimble run {bin[0]} {params} --silent"
```